# Database replication SQL Server 2008 to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, replication

I have to create real time replication from SQL Server 2008 to Mysql. It should be one directional data synchronizing.

Has anybody done this before?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "real time". Realy at the time a record has been added/modified/deleted or are 5 min. OK?

Comment: Yeah, I mean at the time when record has been added/modified/deleted

Answer (score 3):

[SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.org) might be a possibility.

Comment: I just spent some time looking at SymmetricDS and it requires you to be able to install triggers on the master server.  See the FAQ, where they explicitly disallow timestamp based replication: http://www.symmetricds.org/docs/faq

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DBSync](http://www.dbconvert.com/convert-mssql-to-mysql-sync.php) don't know how 'real time' it is though.

Comment: thanks for suggestion but DBSync is bi-directional database migration tool. I'm not sure that it works properly in only one direction, but I'll check

Answer (score 0):

See ObjectMMRS at http://www.object.com.br/wiki - you can try first, it's a multi-master replication suite for heterogeneous database near real time sync.

Comment: i feel loosy 'cause I can't read spanish doc( Thanks for adwise